# Remove localStorage older keys

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```js
function PopUp(show) {
  document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("s<?php echo date('dmY');?>") != 1) {
      window.open("https://www.google.com");
    }
    localStorage.setItem("s<?php echo date('dmY');?>", 1);
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    PopUp('show');
  }, 500);
}
```

I try to delete the older storage keys, can someone help me with correct code? I am new with this and can't figure it out how to do…

Comment: and where are you supposed to remove the older keys?

Comment: And with what part do you have a problem? With iterating through its [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key)? To check if one of those keys matches the one you set with `setItem`? To compare the keys with a certain date to check if it has to be deleted? Or to [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)  an item?

Comment: Sorry, i store the keys in localStorage , i store with keys: s24042023 (wich is current day), i want to delete older keys when i store new dates e.g delete s23042023 when s24042023 is stored ...

Comment: If you want to delete all items referring to an older date, then why do you use a dynamic key, instead of  a static one that holds the date as value?

Comment: you could just have a key `"date"` and store the date as value then whenever you store new dates then do `localStorage.removeItem('date');` first, then store your new date

Comment: or you could directly overwrite that key value with `setItem`

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you seem to be using a `s31122023` date format for the key names, so you can just sort the existing keys and remove the "lowest". The following function adds a new entry (and calculates the new key name on the fly) while deleting the oldest entry. You can change the `> 0` to `> 10` to keep only the 10 newest entries, for example.

```
// Adds an entry to localStorage, removing the oldest entry if any exists.
// Assumes entry keys are in a s31122023 date format.
function addRollingEntry(value) {
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
        const previousKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
        previousKeys.sort();
        localStorage.removeItem(previousKeys[0]);
    }

    const newKey = "s" + newDate().format('ddMMyyyy');
    localStorage.setItem(newKey, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading your comments i managed to do this

```
function PopUp(show) {
            document.addEventListener("click", function() {
                const key = Object.keys(localStorage).find(key => key.includes("show_"));
                if (localStorage.getItem("show_<?php echo date('d'); ?>") != 1) {
                    if (key) {
                        localStorage.removeItem(key);
                    }
                    window.open("https://www.google.com");
                }
                localStorage.setItem("show_<?php echo date('d'); ?>", 1);
            });
        }
```

and now basically removes all keys starting with show_ prefix